# Cordova.exec not calling java plugin asynchronously

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am making a phonegap application and called a native function built in java.I am new to java. Everything is working perfectly fine but its not a asynchronous call-

This is my java code-

```
public class MyPlugin extends CordovaPlugin
{
    Context context;
    @Override
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
        // your init code here
    }
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException 
    {
        context=this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        if (action.equals("plugin1"))
        { 

            callbackContext.success("Operation performed successfully!!");
            return true;
        }
        callbackContext.error("error");
        return false;    
    }
}
```

This is my javascript code-

```
function downloadapk(myurl)
{   
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    cordova.exec(
        function(winparam){
            alert(winparam);
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
        },
        function(errparam){
            alert(errparam);
            $.mobile.loading('hide')
        },
        'MyPlugin','plugin1',[myurl]); 
};
```

My problem is-
When the cordova.exec function works,the $.mobile.loading('show') does not work. But they say that plugin is called asynchronously.I want while this plugin does not return back ,the loading progress bar remains visible on the screen.

I am struck.Please help.. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit:

To create a java process that will call a `javascript` method `async` at the end when it finishes you'll have to create a separate `javascript callback` function that will being called.
You will call it when your task is finished on `JAVA` side.

**Javascript:**

```
myJScallback = function(param){
    //JAVA task is finished so i'm getting called
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
}
```

**JAVA:**

```
private void doSomething() {

    // A S Y N C
    //do your ASYNC stuff here...
    // ...
    // ...


    //once ready call callJSCallback()
    String params = "optional params";
    callJSCallback(params);
}

// obviously you can take out the "params" if you don't need it.
private void callJSCallback(String params) {
    this.sendJavascript("myJScallback('"+params+"');");
}
```

and you have to call this `JAVA` method once you have finished your JAVA side task.

---

#### Original answer:

It does work but your plugin `plugin1` calls the `successCallback` immediately so you probably don't even see the `progress bar` it's so fast.

Add some task to your plugin so it will take a few seconds to finish before it calls the `successCallbac` and you should see the progressbar.

Just a quick test, sleeping the thread for 2 seconds so progressbar should show:

```
if (action.equals("plugin1"))
{ 
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    callbackContext.success("Operation performed successfully!!");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi,this is not a solution to my problem,actually i want to return to javascript code asap. and then run the java function asynchronously. So i need to know how to callback javascript function from asynchronous java function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but this might help you http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins_threading

I used this code especially:

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if ("beep".equals(action)) {
        final long duration = args.getLong(0);
        cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ...
                callbackContext.success(); // Thread-safe.
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```